# How to update table data from a different worksheet on Excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to link two worksheets together such that when I update data from a table in Sheet 2, the numbers in the table automatically gets updated in Sheet 1. Thus, Sheet 2 is the source of update and Sheet 1 is just the output. How would I make this work?

I tried using the SERIES function but it did not work. Maybe because there were no charts involved? Can someone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example? You can try the LOOKUP or VLOOKUP function

Comment: You can use [Pivot Tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no need for you to do anything fancy - just build the equations in the output sheet and click in the data sheet  to insert the cell references.